# using beans in javascript in a jsf form

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a form with different input texts, I want to validate my form in client side, so I have written a java script function and the validation of the form is based on a property in the defined bean(userManagement.update), it means that if userManagement.update is true, these input texts are not required, but if userManagement.update is false, these input texts are required.
the problem is userManagement.update does not change in javascript function.

```
<h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="* #{i18n['password']}: "
                        rendered="#{!userManagement.update}" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value=" #{i18n['password']}: "
                        rendered="#{userManagement.update}" />
                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{userManagement.user.password}"
                        match="pwd2" label="Password 1"
                        required="#{!userManagement.update}"
                        requiredMessage="#{i18n['password_required']}"
                        validatorMessage="#{i18n['password_match_repeat_password']}" />
                    <span style="color: red" id="emptyPasswordError" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="* #{i18n['repeat_password']}: "
                        rendered="#{!userManagement.update}" />
                    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value=" #{i18n['repeat_password']}: "
                        rendered="#{userManagement.update}" />
                    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{userManagement.user.password}"
                        required="#{!userManagement.update}"
                        requiredMessage="#{i18n['repeat_password_required']}" />
                    <span style="color: red" id="emptyRepeatPasswordError" />



<p:commandButton value="#{i18n['update']}"
                actionListener="#{userManagement.update}">
            </p:commandButton>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    if ($("#addUserform:pwd1").val() === "")
    {
        if("#{!userManagement.update}"){
            $("#emptyPasswordError").text("#{i18n['password_required']}"); 
            validation = false; 
        }
    }
    else{
        $("#emptyPasswordError").text("");
    }
    if ($("#addUserform:pwd2").val() === "")
    {
        alert("#{!userManagement.update}");
        if("#{!userManagement.update}"){
            $("#emptyRepeatPasswordError").text( "#{i18n['repeat_password_required']}"); 
            validation = false; 
        }
    }
    else{
        $("#emptyRepeatPasswordError").text("");
    } 
    return validation;
}
</script>
```